# RESTful Call in C# using basic authentication returning error message

Tags: c#, restful-authentication, osb

I am trying to call a Restful service on OSB. My code is:

```
string url = _httpGetText + "&$filter=" + filter;

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("CLLORptngAppIdDev:DPJZuogiYEo5"));
        WebResponse response;

        try
        {
            response = request.GetResponse();
            List<HistoryRequest> histroyRequestList = LoadHistoryRequest(response);
            return histroyRequestList;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;
        }
```

The message in the catch is: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

On the serer side I see this message

```
<responseSelectedForConsumingProxyService>
    <soap-env:Body
        xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap-env:Body>
            <soap-env:Fault>
                <faultcode>Server</faultcode>
                <faultstring>This is an Oracle Service Bus generated fault. 
[OSB-386420 - A web service security error ocurred while producing security header] 
[RouteNode_XXXXXXXXXXXXV_1_0request-pipeline] 
[instanceid - *********************************************;]
</faultstring>
            </soap-env:Fault>
        </soap-env:Body>
    </soap-env:Body>
</responseSelectedForConsumingProxyService>
```

As a result of comments I have also tried the following options with the exact same results:

```
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes("<ID>:<Pssword>"));

String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes("<ID>:<Pssword>"));
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes("<ID>:<Pssword>"));
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

Comment: You are setting contenType request header but not sending anything in request.

Comment: Also, I don't think you can set the content type in this manner. Use property `ContentType`.

Comment: @PankajKapare, I have removed the code that sets the content type in the header and still get the same results.

Comment: @JuanR I have removed the code that sets the content type in the header and still get the same results.

Comment: Have you verified authentication is configured properly on the OSB side?

Comment: Why the down vote. The issue is clearly stated.

Comment: @JuanR the best I can. It is managed by another group and they swear there is no issue on their end (Of Course). I am trying to make sure I have tried everything before I jump up and down and scream to loud.

Comment: How about the encoding for the authorization header? Have you tried using UTF-8?

Comment: Can you check the raw output of your application that includes HTTP headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following code that works:

```
 public List<HistoryRequest> GetHistoryRequestList()
    {
        Configuration roamingConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        string OSBBaseUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OSBUrl"];
        string OSBGetEndPoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OSBEndPoint"];
        string MSDCallerId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppId"];

        string Encoding = "iso-8859-1";
        string Osbpw = HistoryCrypto.Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CipherPass"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CryptoKey"]);

        CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache
        {
            {
                new Uri(OSBBaseUri),
                "NTLM",
                new NetworkCredential()
                {
                    UserName = "<UserName>",
                    Password = Osbpw,
                    Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"]
                }
            }
        };

        HttpMessageHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Credentials = credentialCache
        };

        var _httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(OSBBaseUri),
            Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0),
        };

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("HTTP_Referrer/HistoryRequestProcess"));
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("MSCRMCallerID/"+ MSDCallerId));

        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent("{\"operationssubtypecode\":\"HREQ\"} ", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var method = new HttpMethod("GET");
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage(method, OSBGetEndPoint)
        {
            Content = httpContent
        };

        message.Headers.Add("HTTP_Referrer", "HistoryRequestProcess");
        message.Headers.Add("MSCRMCallerID", MSDCallerId);

        HttpResponseMessage response = _httpClient.GetAsync(OSBGetEndPoint).Result;
        string content = string.Empty;

        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Encoding)))
        {
            content = stream.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return LoadHistoryRequest(content);
    }
```